# A word for the area right in front of a door?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word that is specific to the area right in front of a door, especially the outside area of a door. The word *entrance* is too broad, because that could be inside or outside. I need to specify outside.

Comment: Threshold, perhaps?  [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/threshold) has a broader definition than some: **threshold** noun:  _the floor of an entrance to a building or room_

Comment: How do you want to use this word?  Can you provide an example sentence?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *Threshold* has a very specific meaning. It is the strip of wood or stone immediately under the door when closed , and forming the bottom of the doorway. I think the OP is thinking here of the *arc* through which a door swings. I believe the term is "the door's arc". At least I cannot think of any other name for it, unless it is the *door swing*. .

Comment: @WS2 'Hurricane' also has a very specific meaning. And a less specific one, which is used more often. Words are often polysemic. I gave the broader definition CDO provides; the normal usage is far broader, being metaphorical. [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/threshold) differs again: 'noun
1.
the sill of a doorway.
2.
the entrance to a house or building.' ...

Comment: A _stoop_ is "a porch, platform, entrance stairway, or small veranda at a house door".

Comment: I have always called the small paved area outside the door of a house the doorstep, even when it doesn't have steps.  Dictionaries define doorstep as the step or steps leading to an outer door of a house.  Perhaps, I've been using the wrong word my whole life, though.  Oxford Living Dictionaries has an example sentence that might agree with my conception. ‘Then he opened the door and stepped out onto the doorstep.’  https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/doorstep

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth The term "doorstep" can be used widely. And as you have felt a need to point out, we can be speaking literally or more widely here. Often people refer to the Prime Minister speaking from "the steps of Downing Street". But if you look at [this picture of David Cameron](http://www.zimbio.com/pictures/73KTcwwjS6k/Downing+Street+Last+Day+Parliament+Before/B5pYPDamIRD) you will see that he is nowhere near "the steps", but actually standing out in the road.

Comment: The term I use--e.g., to tell UPS where to leave a package--is "outside the front door."  Note that the some AmEnglish dialects have a phrase:  "the door yard," which may mean something more than you intend.

Comment: @Palizsche That would only apply to the outside door of a building. The doors to rooms, suites or apartments don't usually have doorsteps. In fact a lot of them open off carpeted spaces, but if you are knocking at the door you're still standing in the space the OP wants a word for.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this question on the basis that it is not clear what the questioner is asking. Is it the literal space, a metaphorical term, or what? And since we have been thrashing this around between ourselves the OP appears to have made no effort to clarify what they are talking about.

Comment: @WS2 I was pointing out the two physical/locational usages (the sill; the general area) allowed by say Dictionary.com and merely stressing that the metaphorical usage is another possibility to show that though 'Threshold has a very specific meaning', '_threshold_' does not need to have this very specific meaning.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was making no complaint about your contribution, Edwin. In fact I quite agree. The term *threshold* is used in all sorts of metaphorical senses e.g. *He stood on the threshold of a political career*. I was merely complaining that the OP, other than having asked a somewhat vague question seems to be taking no further interest.

Comment: If there's a raised area between the door and the lawn or walkway, it's called a "porch".

Comment: @Barmar But doesn't "porch" imply some sort of roof or sheltered area?

Comment: @neu242 You're right. I think if it's not sheltered like that we generally don't consider it a "thing" that gets named.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there are no stairs immediately outside the door, "stoop" is what New Yorkers would say.

Comment: The outside of most doors is still *within* a building. (That's why you shouldn't answer these questions, but flag/vote to close them instead.)

Comment: It's always good to hear what various speakers say, but do you have a reference for your answer?